# Lost ability to capture unique Conversation_ID for each new session

Tags: azure, botframework

Using Bot Builder 4.11.1 .Net and seemed to have lost the ability to capture any unique identifier for each new session.  I need a unique identifier to keep state with the AI engine I am using to respond to input.  Any suggestions?  So, to expand, if I have a slack bot, for example, each time a user logs into Slack and starts a conversation with MyBot, I need a new unique identifier.

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var welcomeText = "Hello and welcome!";
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(welcomeText, welcomeText), cancellationToken);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you were doing before and what results you are getting now? I'm guessing Slack may be like Microsoft Teams, where you conversationID does not change, i.e. it's just one conversation that lasts forever? I track unique conversations in App Insights by looking at conversationID + date but I don't know if that addresses your issue.

Comment: I think what I am seeing is that using the newer MSFT Bot Framework, I no longer have access to the unique Conversation_ID or Session_ID when a request comes in for a new conversation.  In my case, a new conversation means not only creating the connection to the AI Server, but also loading the appropriate intents, entities, etc based on the incoming request.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow. Can you maybe post a sample of the code you were using to get the IDs before and what errors you're getting now? I'm admittedly using syntax and methods from an early SDK4 release but I have done a bit of work with conversation reference from the context of proactive messaging.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase, as this has nothing to do with Slack.  I need to find a unique string variable that gets set when a new session  starts.  I can see in EchoBot.cs that there is a section in the class EchoBot that is just for the first time a session initiates.  I'll post the code at the end of my original question.  I am sure that somewhere in this code is the variable that I am looking for.  Then I need to make it public or stuff it in a public string variable so I can use it in my SilviaRestClass.  It's been a long time since I've done C# code, so I am really rusty.

Comment: @billoverton. Thanks for your comments.  how are you deriving conversationID in your code.  It probably does address my issue, but I don't know where to find that or where to insert the code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to get the information you need from `TurnContext`. In my code I'm running this in `onMessage` only (as in my case I only will message the user if they have sent the bot a message), but I don't see why you couldn't use this in `onMembersAdded` as well. I don't know how channels like Slack work, but in Microsoft Teams the user is just "added" when they first talk to the bot, and you don't end up in `onMembersAdded` unless they remove and read the bot in Teams. So if you may want to grab the conversation reference in the future, you may want to have it in `onMessage` or in both places. Also if you need the activity ID for some reason, as this will obviously update with each activity (though I haven't had any need for this information). Here is how you get the conversation reference. I am storing this in my conversation state and have assumed you are familiar with that but let me know if you need further help there. I also store in an Azure table to be accessed outside of the bot (e.g. I have an Azure Function that uses this to send proactive followups).

```js
const { TurnContext } = require('botbuilder');

const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(context, {});
conversationData.conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
```

And that's it! Here is a sample conversation reference. Note that if you are storing this in Azure Tables or similar, you'll likely need to stringify it and re-parse when you pull it out.

```js
{
    "activityId":"ACTIVITY_ID",
    "user": {
        "id":"USER_ID",
        "name":"USER_NAME",
        "aadObjectId":"AAD_OBJECT_ID",
        "role":"user"
    },
    "bot": {
        "id":"BOT_ID",
        "name":"BOT_NAME"
    },
    "conversation": { 
        "conversationType":"personal",
        "tenantId":"YOUR_TENANT_ID",
        "id":"YOUR_CONVERSATION_ID"
    },
    "channelId":"msteams",
    "locale":"en-US",
    "serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/"
}
```

What you are looking for (I think) is `conversationReference.conversation.id`. Different channels are going to have different attributes in the conversation reference, but this ID should always be there.